# Abstracting configuration in Pulumi

Tags: configuration, pulumi

I've been learning Pulumi (really great tool!) and I've the following scenario. Let's assume that I've a bunch of resources which I'd like to deploy to multiple environemnts. For each of the environments, I'd like to have different names (for example, ResourceGroup in dev == "dev", qa =="qa" etc.). How can I achieve that with Pulumi ? What I'd like to avoid is having all the configurations (for all the envs) added in one Pulumi config file. With a small number of resources it may work, but with a bigger number, I guess this file will become unreadable. The only solution that comes to my mind is to have a component created for all of the resources and then create a stack for every single environment, which can use the component with the resources. But maybe there's a better option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulumi [stacks](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/stack/) are designed specifically for this. You can have one pulumi project file that can be deployed into multiple environments via stacks.

To get diferent names per stack:

1. [Create a stack](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/stack/#create-stack) with environment name, for example:

   ```sh
   pulumi stack init dev
   ```
2. Use [`pulumi.getStack()`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/stack/#getting-the-current-stack-programmatically) to get stack name inside your code.

   It will looks something like this:

   ```js
   const stack = pulumi.getStack()

   const resourceGroup = new azure.core.ResourceGroup("group", {
     name: `group-{stack}` // use stack name as part of resource name
     location: "West US"
   });
   ```

   > This example is for JS, but you can find references for other languages in linked docs

In addition to stack names, you can also have separate [configuration](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/config/) values per stack -  https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/project/#stack-settings-file

---

- See [Organizing projects stacks](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/organizing-projects-stacks/) for more infor on how to organize your stacks and environments.
- More real [example](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/258d3bad0a00020704743e37911c51be63c06bb4/aws-ts-apigatewayv2-http-api/index.ts) of using [stack name](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/258d3bad0a00020704743e37911c51be63c06bb4/aws-ts-apigatewayv2-http-api/index.ts#L18) as part of [resource name](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/258d3bad0a00020704743e37911c51be63c06bb4/aws-ts-apigatewayv2-http-api/index.ts#L76-L78)